# Android: business logic transformation in Repository/ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, repository-pattern

I have a repository class:

```
class RepositoryImpl(private val application: Application) :
    Repository {
    override suspend fun getCities(): Resource<List<City>> =
        try {
            val bufferReader = application.assets.open(CITIES_FILE_NAME).bufferedReader()
            val data = bufferReader.use {
                it.readText()
            }
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<City?>?>() {}.type
            val fromJson = gson.fromJson<List<City>>(data, type)
            Resource.Success(fromJson)
        } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
            Resource.Error(JSONSYNTAXEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Resource.Error(IOEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE)
        }
```

and the `Resource` class is:

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

I need to fetch the cities and I do it in my VM like this:

```
class CityListViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    @VisibleForTesting
    val allCities: LiveData<Resource<List<City>>> =
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            val cities: Resource<List<City>> = repository.getCities().sortedBy { city: City -> city.name }
            emit(cities)
        }
}
```

The problem, is that I modeled my repository to wrap the list of cities in a `Resource` and I need to sort the cities alphabetically, so the line `val cities: Resource<List<City>> = repository.getCities().sortedBy { city: City -> city.name }` does not compile.

Am I doing it wrong like this? The repository just takes care of retrieving the data and wrapping it in the `Resource` and the business logic lies in the VM, but now it receives a `Resource` and needs to access the data, sort it, and put it back in the `Resource` so the `Activity` knows what to do depending on the whether it's a `Success`, `Error` or `Loading`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Theoretically if you were using a DB underneath rather than a file, the way it'd work is that you would expose a `getCitiesSortedByCityName()` from the Repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your data before emiting to the UI:

```
...
emit(Resource.Loading())
val resource = repository.getCities().map {
    if (it is Resource.Success) {
        Resource.Success(it.data.sortedBy { city: City -> city.name })
    } else {
        it
    }
}
emit(resource)
...
```